# Deep copying in getters for mutable object

Tags: java, oop

Would it be overhead to always return a copy of collection/object field?

Comment: Sorry, but "would it be overhead" clearly goes into the "give me your opinions" ballpark. In that sense, your question doesn't fit here. My opinion: it really depends. If your design works better if you return copies, then do that. If it is important that all parties are dealing with the **same** objects, then maybe you don't create clones.

Comment: Semi-related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192762/inefficiency-of-defensive-copy-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, yes it would be a overhead ... compared with returning a reference or a shallow copy.

But that's not really the point.  The real point is whether the overhead is warranted / necessary, and whether it can be avoided by using some other data structure / design / technique.  The answer to those questions depends on the context.

---

Here are some illustrations:

1. If a target object getter returns an immutable object, a copy is unnecessary.  Example, any getter that returns a `String`.
2. If a target object getter returns an object that is not part of the target object abstraction, a copy is undesirable.  Example `list.get(int)`, `Iterator.next()`.
3. If a target object getter returns a mutable object (or array) **AND** the returned object is part of the object's internal state **AND** the target doesn't necessarily trust the caller, then the getter should either copy it or wrap it ... or there may be a security problem.
4. The same may apply in non-security-related contexts; e.g. `ArrayList.toArray(...)` copies the list into an separate array rather than returning the list's backing array.  (Similar for `getChars()` for a `String`, `StringBuffer`, etc.)  This is all about maintaining the abstraction boundary so that on class won't "break" another one.
5. If a target object getter returns a mutable object (or array) **AND** the returned object is part of the object's internal state **BUT** the target object's API / abstraction boundary is *designed to be "porous"* (e.g. for performance reasons), then copying may be self defeating.

Of these, 3 is the only case where cloning is strictly mandatory.  In 2, 4 and 5 you could argue that it is a matter of how you design the public (or internal) APIs for the classes, libraries, applications.  And often there are many viable choices.

Comment: @StephenC It would be really great if you could give some examples when it's necessary to clone objects in getters of mutable objects

Answer (score 1):

It is overhead for sure but there are already some framework classes which do that. It is also described in the book Effective Java.

Remember:

> "Classes should be immutable unless there's a very good reason to make them mutable....If a class cannot be made immutable, limit its mutability as much as possible."

When you want to create immutable classes than you can use a framework like that: http://immutables.github.io

For examples check this [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html)